# Obtain product custom field value in Virtuemart

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I am trying to obtain value of a custom field of a product. I only have ID of that product. I know title of the custom field.

How can I get value of that custom field?

Please help.

PS: I know PHP well but I am new to Joomla/Virtuemart.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for VM2.x

VM is storing the custom field values in #__virtuemart_customs

The relation between the product and the custom field is maintaining in the #__virtuemart_product_customfields

You have title and Product Id so you can try this

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT F.custom_value #__virtuemart_customs AS C LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_product_customfields AS F ON F.virtuemart_customfield_id = C.virtuemart_custom_id where (C.custom_title='$your_customtitle' and F.virtuemart_product_id = '$product_id')";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->query();
$res = $db->loadAssoc();
echo $res['custom_value'];
```

Also you try with inner sub query .

Answer (score -1):

```
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('virtuemart_product_id,custom_value');
    $query->from('#__virtuemart_product_customfields');
    $db->setQuery((string)$query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    if ($results){
    foreach($results as $result) 
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
```